# Edit two xml files

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml file like this:

```
 <CompletePPCallback>
 <MessageId>9133235059913398501</MessageId>
 <keyB>keyBkeyBkeyB</keyB>
 <filename>c:\temp\log\SMKFFcompleteProductionPlan.xml</filename>
 </CompletePPCallback>
```

Where tag 'filename' is the path to another xml file. Example of this file:

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
        <soapenv:Body>
            <ns2:completeProductionPlan
                xmlns='http://ServiceManagement/OIS_Services_v01.00/common'
xmlns:ns2='http://ServiceManagement/TechnicalOrderManagement/ProductionFulfillment_v01.00/types'>
                <ns2:messageID>
                    <value>9133235059913398501_9133235059913398860</value>
                </ns2:messageID>
            </ns2:completeProductionPlan>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now I need to create xsl file that will copy the second xml file and change the value of the messageID from the first xml file. Something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns2="http://ServiceManagement/TechnicalOrderManagement/ProductionFulfillment_v01.00/types"
    xmlns:common="http://ServiceManagement/OIS_Services_v01.00/common"
    exclude-result-prefixes="ns2 common">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />


    <xsl:variable name="providerXMLpath">
        <xsl:value-of select="//filename" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="providerMessageId">
        <xsl:value-of select="document($providerXMLpath)//ns2:messageID/common:value" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="document($providerXMLpath)"/> 
    </copy>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <FirstTag>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test='$providerMessageId=//MessageId'>
                    <tag>
                        <xsl:text>Equal</xsl:text>
                    </tag>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <tag>
                        <xsl:text>Different</xsl:text>
                    </tag>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </FirstTag>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can I change the value of the copy xml file?

Edit.
Output xml what I want to get:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
            <soapenv:Body>
                <ns2:completeProductionPlan
                    xmlns='http://ServiceManagement/OIS_Services_v01.00/common'
    xmlns:ns2='http://ServiceManagement/TechnicalOrderManagement/ProductionFulfillment_v01.00/types'>
                    <ns2:messageID>
                        <value>9133235059913398501</value>
                    </ns2:messageID>
                </ns2:completeProductionPlan>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Second update:

```
Now I have this xml:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns2:completeProductionPlan
            xmlns="http://ServiceManagement/OIS_Services_v01.00/common"
            xmlns:ns2="http://ServiceManagement/TechnicalOrderManagement/ProductionFulfillment_v01.00/types">
            <ns2:messageID>
                <value>9133235059913398501_9133235059913398860</value>
            </ns2:messageID>
            <ns2:productionPlan>
                <entityKey>
                    <keyA>9c4332b3-e60d-466b-9ab8-1187e98582e9</keyA>
                </entityKey>
                <state>
                    <value>readyForCompletion</value>
                </state>
                <service>
                    <entityKey>
                        <keyB>f51c2436-1a8e-4411-9a95-4eed04bcb412</keyB>
                    </entityKey>
                    <specification>
                        <specificationName>Access_Line</specificationName>
                        <specificationID>Access_Line</specificationID>
                        <characteristic>
                            <characteristicID>SpecificationType</characteristicID>
                            <characteristicValue>RFS</characteristicValue>
                        </characteristic>
                    </specification>
                </service>
                <service>
                    <entityKey>
                        <keyB>29b81be7-94e0-47e7-82f7-884ad57755d7</keyB>
                    </entityKey>
                    <specification>
                        <specificationName>Workforce_Recherche</specificationName>
                        <specificationID>Workforce_Recherche</specificationID>
                        <characteristic>
                            <characteristicID>SpecificationType</characteristicID>
                            <characteristicValue>RFS</characteristicValue>
                        </characteristic>
                    </specification>    
                </service>
            </ns2:productionPlan>
        </ns2:completeProductionPlan>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to replace the value of 'keyB' tag from this last code example by the value 'keyB' tag("keyBkeyBkeyB") from the first xml example if its child tag 'specificationName' is equal Workforce_Recherche value. Can I do it with identity template? I have several tags 'keyB' and 'specificationName' but need to change only one value with properties described above.

I want to get:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns2:completeProductionPlan
            xmlns="http://ServiceManagement/OIS_Services_v01.00/common"
            xmlns:ns2="http://ServiceManagement/TechnicalOrderManagement/ProductionFulfillment_v01.00/types">
            <ns2:messageID>
                <value>9133235059913398501</value>
            </ns2:messageID>
            <ns2:productionPlan>
                <entityKey>
                    <keyA>9c4332b3-e60d-466b-9ab8-1187e98582e9</keyA>
                </entityKey>
                <state>
                    <value>readyForCompletion</value>
                </state>
                <service>
                    <entityKey>
                        <keyB>f51c2436-1a8e-4411-9a95-4eed04bcb412</keyB>
                    </entityKey>
                    <specification>
                        <specificationName>Access_Line</specificationName>
                        <specificationID>Access_Line</specificationID>
                        <characteristic>
                            <characteristicID>SpecificationType</characteristicID>
                            <characteristicValue>RFS</characteristicValue>
                        </characteristic>
                    </specification>
                </service>
                <service>
                    <entityKey>
                        <keyB>keyBkeyBkeyB</keyB>
                    </entityKey>
                    <specification>
                        <specificationName>Workforce_Recherche</specificationName>
                        <specificationID>Workforce_Recherche</specificationID>
                        <characteristic>
                            <characteristicID>SpecificationType</characteristicID>
                            <characteristicValue>RFS</characteristicValue>
                        </characteristic>
                    </specification>    
                </service>
            </ns2:productionPlan>
        </ns2:completeProductionPlan>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Do you want to keep your second XML in generated output as it is except some change in ns2:messageID/value element?

Comment: I want to replace ns2:messageID/value by MessageId tag value from first xml. In general, I want to know how to edit copy xml tags and values: add new tags, change values and etc.

Comment: Could you please add an example for expected output xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using copy-of there is no way to change any thing.

Therefore:
Use an **identity transform** for the second file.
Make the content of the first file accessible as variable (if you need more than one value from this. If only one value should be changed you can also use the variable providerMessageId).
And special templates for values which should be changed depending on first file. (E.g ns2:messageID/common:value)

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns2="http://ServiceManagement/TechnicalOrderManagement/ProductionFulfillment_v01.00/types"
    xmlns:common="http://ServiceManagement/OIS_Services_v01.00/common"
    exclude-result-prefixes="ns2 common">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="providerXMLpath">
        <xsl:value-of select="//filename" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="completePPCallback" select="CompletePPCallback" />

    <xsl:variable name="providerMessageId">
        <xsl:value-of select="document($providerXMLpath)//ns2:messageID/common:value" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns2:messageID/common:value">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="$completePPCallback/MessageId"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document($providerXMLpath)/*" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Update generated output:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns2:completeProductionPlan xmlns="http://ServiceManagement/OIS_Services_v01.00/common" 
                                    xmlns:ns2="http://ServiceManagement/TechnicalOrderManagement/ProductionFulfillment_v01.00/types">
            <ns2:messageID>
                <value>9133235059913398501</value>
            </ns2:messageID>
        </ns2:completeProductionPlan>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: if I run this code it returns me only `<MessageId>9133235059913398501_9133235059913398860</MessageId>`. I hoped that I could copy my xml and edit(( Thank you. I will try to do with identity transform myself

Comment: I fail to see what you mean. The output is the content of  file 2  but the ns2:messageID/value is from MessageId form file 1.

Comment: generated output is `<MessageId>9133235059913398501_9133235059913398860</MessageId>` for my example

Comment: I found my mistake) Your example now works very fine for me) thank you)

Comment: I can't solve new problem. Please, read my update and give me your answer for this question

Comment: Add a new template: ` <xsl:template match="common:service[*/common:specificationName='Workforce_Recherche']/*/common:keyB">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:value-of select="$completePPCallback/keyB"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>`

Comment: This returns error: 'JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker - prefix must perform a translation into the namespace: common??;' on this line: <xsl:template match="common:service[*/common:specificationName='Workforce_Recherche']/*/common‌​:keyB">

Comment: I create my own template: `<xsl:template match="ns2:productionPlan//common:service/common:entityKey/common:keyB">
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="translate(../..//common:specificationName, ' ', '_')='Workforce_Recherche'">
    <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:value-of select="$completePPCallback/keyB" />
    </xsl:copy>  
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:element name="keyB">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </xsl:element>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>` but your variant is more better if I can use)